# On-premise browser synthetic monitoring

Tags: web-browser

We are currently using a cloud hosted product for our browser [synthetic monitoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_monitoring).

We now need to monitor sites that are only accessible from our network.

Can anyone recommend a on-premise browser synthetic monitoring product?